# qrule mathematic interpolation in quantile estimation in R survey package

Tags: r, survey, quantiles, median

I've been having difficulty understanding the code for `qrule_math` in the `survey` package. [This document here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/vignettes/qrule.pdf) says this about it:

[image]

However, this is not what the code seems to do. Given two vectors of values (x) and weights (w) and a quantile (p) of 0.5 to find the median value:

```
x <- structure(c(577450.791535772, 919590.385520716, 755016.909933021, 
1515808.3277814), .Dim = c(1L, 4L), .Dimnames = list("ing_t_p_R", 
    c("11110", "31250", "113113", "113118")))
w <- c(`11110` = 311.909858216766, `31250` = 59.2529837088652, `113113` = 34.1247483726328, 
`113118` = 69.4310625894021)
p <- 0.5

#First define helper function last():
last <- function (a) 
   {
     if (any(a)) 
       max(which(a))
     else 1
   }
```

Function `qs` finds an upper and a lower quantile:

```
    qs <- function (x, w, p) 
   {
     n <- length(x)
     ii <- order(x)
     x <- x[ii]
     cumw <- cumsum(w[ii])
     pos <- last(cumw <= p * sum(w))
     posnext <- if (pos == length(x)) 
       pos
     else pos + 1
     list(qlow = x[pos], qup = x[posnext], ilow = pos, iup = posnext, 
          wlow = p - cumw[pos]/sum(w), wup = cumw[posnext]/sum(w) - 
            p)
   }
```

Then, qrule_math has a condition where it outputs the lower quantile only if `wlow` is equal to zero:

```
qrule_math <- function (x, w, p) {
      
      qdata <- qs(x, w, p)
            
      if (qdata$wlow == 0) 
        qdata$qlow
      else qdata$qup
    }
```

So applying `qrule_math` to given x, w and p you get:

```
qrule_math(x,w,p)
[1] 755016.9
```

It gets you the upper quantile. This is different from output given by Stata and calculation "by hand" (577451).

So, my question is:

1. Is this output correct?
2. What does it mean the condition given inside `qrule_math` function, where it gives the lower quantile only if `wlow` is equal to zero? Shouldn't this function give always the quantile that satisfies to be <= p?

Comment: Why do you use these bizarre numbers for your example?  Test first with a simple dataset, such as `c(1,2)` or `c(1,2,3,4)`. That will enable you easily to check that `qrule_math` does what it claims (or not--I can only speak to the one example you have supplied).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch! This looks to me like a bug. Inside `qrule_math()`, the condition should be `if (qdata$wlow <= 0)` rather than `==`.

The `==` makes sense in the "typical" situation where `p >= min(w)/sum(w)`, so that `wlow` is non-negative. Then `qrule_math()` should always return the upper quantile `qup` unless you're exactly on the lower quantile.

But it misses the possibility that `p` might be smaller than the smallest `w`'s proportion of `sum(w)`.

In your case, the weight `w` corresponding to the smallest `x` is over half of `sum(w)`, so you get a negative `wlow`. In that situation, `qrule_math()` should be returning `min(x)`... but because it (mistakenly) assumed `wlow` will always be non-negative, it only checks for `wlow==0` and incorrectly returns the 2nd-smallest `x`.

---

Simplified example, based on your example data:

```r
x <- c(5,9,7,15)
w <- c(300, 60, 30, 70)
p <- 0.5

# Reorder to make it easier to think about
w <- w[order(x)]
x <- x[order(x)]

x
## [1]  5  7  9 15
cumsum(w)
## [1] 300 330 390 460
cumsum(w)/sum(w)
## [1] 0.6521739 0.7173913 0.8478261 1.0000000
```

So for instance you'd expect:

- `p=0.5` should return `x[1]` which is 5
- `p=0.7` should return `x[2]` which is 7
- `p=sum(w[1:2])/sum(w)` should *also* return `x[2]` which is 7
- `p=0.72` should return `x[3]` which is 9

BUT the current `qrule_math()` wrongly returns 7 for the first of these.

```r
qrule_math(x,w,.5)
## [1] 7
qrule_math(x,w,.7)
## [1] 7
qrule_math(x,w,sum(w[1:2]/sum(w)))
## [1] 7
qrule_math(x,w,.72)
## [1] 9
```

However, if we fix `==` to `<=`, it works:

```r
qrule_math_fixed <- function (x, w, p) {
  qdata <- qs(x, w, p)
  if (qdata$wlow <= 0) 
    qdata$qlow
  else qdata$qup
} 

qrule_math_fixed(x,w,.5)
## [1] 5
qrule_math_fixed(x,w,.7)
## [1] 7
qrule_math_fixed(x,w,sum(w[1:2]/sum(w)))
## [1] 7
qrule_math_fixed(x,w,.72)
## [1] 9
```

Besides `qrule_math()` aka `qrule_hf1()`, there seems to be a related issue in `qrule_school()` aka `qrule_hf2()`, and in `qrule_hf3()`. I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to know when a fix would be ready for this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know! Does `survey::oldsvyquantile()` have the same problem? If not, could you use that until this one is fixed?

Comment: Seems `oldsvyquantile` is fine. I guess it will have to do for now. Thanks!